# Would used for willingness in the present

Tags: modal-verbs

In Macmillan **would** has such usage [Source](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/would)：

> used when you think someone is willing to do something
> *Bruce would lend you the money, I'm sure.*

I thought this usage is only for willingness in the past. Now it can refer to the present!

I wonder if this usage is common in everyday speech (both British and American). If I substitute "could", "will" or "might" for "would", will this bring any subtle differences?

Comment: The past events, the hypothetical thinking, and being polite are all intertwined because in English unreal (irrealis) mood is expressed in the past tense.

Comment: Perhaps what I concern about is how such usage is derived from one of the common usages of **would**.

Comment: Because it's not only about tenses, in this case it's about moods (modality). (which is why "would" is classified as a modal verb.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usages of "would" are almost endless. Even though one definition of the word is a past tense of "will", in this case it is more like a prediction, almost "future tense". Read [Merriam Webster's Definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would)

"You know Bruce *would* loan you the money, just ASK for it!"

"Bruce is running for Governor. He would loan you the money if you could get that bill passed."

As to your second question, absolutely. Each of those words could be substituted for "would" and the sentence would have a completely different meaning.

"Could" would say that he has the money, therefore he *can* lend it to you, but it gives no hint as to whether Bruce would be inclined to do so.

"Will" says that Bruce has the money and will be happy to loan it to you. That Bruce will make the loan is assured.

"Might" is a big question mark. Hmmm, it's worth a shot.

Comment: "Would" says that it is very likely for him to lend you money, right? I thought the whole picture is **If you asked Bruce, he would lend you the money.** I have on idea how **"I'm sure"** is derived from this if-clause. @Jolenealaska

Comment: The speaker says, "Bruce would loan you the money." That means that the speaker predicts both that Bruce has the money and that he will loan it if you ask. He's pretty sure, or he'd use a different word than "would". "Would" in this context also means that something else has to happen. Here, Bruce will loan you the money *if* you ask.

Comment: "Bruce would loan you the money if you would just swallow your pride and ask for the loan." @ZhanlongZheng

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Consider this: "Bruce would *have* loaned you the money."

Comment: I figured out "could" and "might” scenarios, but I don't think it's different from **Bruce will lend you the money, I'm sure.**

Comment: "Would" says that (assuming you ask), but "could" and "might" are very different. "Will" says that the loan is assured. "Could" and "might" are very less certain. He might say no.

Comment: I just don't think **Bruce would lend you the money** is different from **Bruce will lend you the money**.

Comment: "Would" is still depending upon something else happening. "Bruce *would* loan you the money, but you have to beg for it." Another option: "Bruce *would* loan you the money *if* he had it.

Comment: "Bruce *will* loan you the money." It's as if he has already been asked and has cash in hand to give you.

Comment: Your last line sums it up, but his loaning only exists in speaker's imagination, I guess.

Comment: So "Bruce will loan you the money." means "Bruce is ready for loaning you the money."?

Comment: Yes. "Will" says it's a done deal. The speaker is *sure*. It doesn't say specifically that Bruce is aware that he is about to loan money, but he will.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng If Bruce *will* loan the money, all conditions for the loan have been met. If Bruce *would* loan the money, there is still a condition that needs to be met. That condition may only be for you to ask, it may be that you need to slay a dragon first.

Comment: OK! Can I interpret it this way: having said that, I understand there is a condition for me to meet. But what if I can't figure out what the condition is? Then what should I do?

Comment: That's why we have *context*!

Comment: Can you plz invent a dialog or something to give a context of this **would** example?

Comment: You could add that to your answer for improvement.

Comment: Now I think Macmillan is misleading here. would here does not represent a willingness. It's more of a prediction as in " That would be John knocking on the door." What do you think? @Jolenealaska

Comment: In this case, no, I think would *does* suggest willingness. It also does predict that Bruce will loan the money *if* whatever condition has been met. So *prediction* is correct too, but very different from "That would be John knocking on the door."

Comment: As for "That would be John knocking on the door.", I see no conditions here. I am confused.

Comment: That's a big part of why it's a different usage.

Comment: As for "What I'd really like is some tea.", is the same usage as in "Bruce would lend you the money."?

Comment: Nope, that's a different usage yet, expressing desire.

Comment: Is there an implied hypothetical scenario in "That would be John knocking on the door."?

Comment: Sure, that scenario would be that there are at least two people on one side of the door (the speaker needs to speaking to someone), there is a knock at the door, the people can't *see* John (otherwise the word would be *is*, not *would*), and the speaker has reason to believe that the person knocking is John.

Comment: I knew this; what I mean is "if **what**, that would be John."

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I mean if **what happened**, that would be John. e.g. I would leave if John was here. There should be an implicit unreal condition to go with "that would be John".

Comment: Nope, not necessary. The scenario I explained above would be plenty, of course your scenario would also use "would".

Comment: OK. Let me put it this way. Your scenario is not unreal, so would is not apt here. I think it should be "that will be John."

Comment: No, "will be" implies in the future. If someone is at the door, that's in the present.

Comment: "That would be John" is not a very common turn of phrase, usually you'd just say "That's John".

Comment: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/will_1  the 5th sense of will

Comment: Yes, that's the use in the original scenario, Bruce and the money.